# Do we need to delete cookies after session has ended?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Sorry, I'm new to php and I'm just wondering are Cookies during sessions terminated after the session ends and if yes, why ? 
Thankyou.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us???

Comment: Sessions and cookies are not the same. So when a session is deleted the cookie will remain and vice versa

Comment: You may want to read the fine [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Comment: If the session has ended, then presumably the user is not using the site.  How do you plan to delete a cookie on the user's computer if the user isn't making requests to the site?

Answer (score 0):

While a session is supposed to terminate when the user leaves the website, the cookie is meant to store data for the next visit as well. So, no **you should not terminate a cookie.**

This is not only the case for PHP, it's just what cookies are for:

> An HTTP cookie, is a small piece of data sent from a website and **stored in a user's web browser** while the user is browsing that website. Every time the user loads the website, the browser sends the cookie back to the server to notify the website of the user's previous activity. Cookies were designed to be a reliable mechanism for websites **to remember stateful information**. *- Wikipedia*

Comment: Ummmm ... session cookies beg to differ.

Comment: @CD001 The question starts with *I'm new to PHP*, I don't think it's relevant to discuss about session cookies. But next time I'll consult my lawyer before posting an answer. :-)